# Cakephp Requires Controller

Tags: php, cakephp

Can anyone help me,

i developed my application with Cakephp 2.1, and it works fine on my development server running Centos 5.7. My challenge came when i transfer my application to the lice server to be accessed by on LAN. It states that a missing controller which is not available in my whole application, for example, i named my folder which contains my application and uploaded to the correct folder in Centos, e.g /var/www/html/students and every time i need to access the application states that students controller is missing. I tried to rename my folder to 'mysite' and the errors still remain with mysite controller is missing.

So everytime i changed the name of the folder it states a missing controller for that named folder. I tried to figure out in core.php but cant find the solution.

Comment: Have you copied all the .htaccess files over properly?

Answer (score 0):

To change the base directory to say /mysite you will have to modify your 3 .htaccess of cakephp i.e one in installlation folder , second inside the app folder,third inside the webroot folder

try adding:-

```
RewriteBase    /mysite/
```

Hope this helps!